# Ajax request through jQuery vs normal call

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-status-code-403

I am doing a normal request to the following page through Chrome browser to the below URL which which gives me the expected result:

```
https://example.com/test.xsl/getLastPost.htm?Project_ID=xyz-Intra
```

However when the same page is called through AJAX from the index page, which actually makes the call to the URL same as the url mentioned above, this gives out

> Request Method: POST
>       Status Code: 403 Forbidden

But but in the response of the developer tools, I see the response from the server. So the ajax call is working perfectly other than that it is not being displayed as it should be and Chrome giving out 403 Forbidden

```js
var $url = 'getLastPost.htm';
var post = $.post($url, {
  "Project_ID": "xyz-Intra"
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

This error is only on Chrome. When the same index page is run through Mozilla or Edge the AJAX call returns data successfully.

What are the possible reasons for this behaviour?

Comment: Is there some method of authentication required to view the URL?

Comment: Yes there is an sso Active directory authentification for the application.

Comment: In that case it means either Chrome hasn't authenticated before you attempt to make the request, or it is not sending the necessary headers automatically.

Comment: Is it possible to see the headers which are sent by chrome vs edge ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the dev tools to view the network requests. Usually it's the F12 key

Comment: Yeah the headers are different when seen through the dev tools. Also Chrome is not making use of the cookie generated by the sso authentification. But how are the headers working properly on edge but headers are not defined in Chrome?